# How can I assign value to a variable inside a UI component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I am relatively new to React and Javascript. I am trying to declare a temporary variable and assign the value companyData.name to it as I need to collect the 2 variables like companyData.name.

This is my code.

```
<Box sx={{ flexGrow: 3 }} display="flex"
        justifyContent="center"
        alignItems="center" marginLeft={8} marginRight={1} mt={2.5}>
        <Grid container spacing={{ xs: 1, md: 2, lg: 2 }} columns={{ xs: 2, sm: 2, md: 12, lg: 16 }} display="flex"
          justifyContent="center"
          alignItems="center" >

          <Grid item xs={2} sm={4} md={6} lg={7.3} >
            Company 1:
          <Box
                sx={{ flexGrow: 1, alignItems: "baseline" }}
                display="flex"
                justifyContent="flex-end"
                alignItems="flex-end">
                <Grid item sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }} spacing={{ xs: 1, md: 2, lg: 2 }} columns={{ xs: 2, sm: 2, md: 12, lg: 22 }} display="flex"
                    justifyContent="center"
                    alignItems="center" marginLeft={8} marginRight={1} mt={4} mb="30px" width='100%'>

                    <Autocomplete
                        id="input"
                        options={allCompanies}
                        renderInput={(params) => {
                            const { InputLabelProps, InputProps, ...rest } = params;
                            return <InputBase placeholder='Search for a company...' sx={{ color: light ? "white" : "black", width: "100%" }} {...params.InputProps} {...rest} />
                        }}
                        onChange={(event, value) => fetchCompanyData(value)}
                        color="primary"
                        style={{ width: "75%", border: light ? "1px solid white" : "1px solid black", borderRadius: "15px", padding: "10px" }}
                        defaultValue={companyData.name}
                        
                       
                    />

                </Grid>


            </Box>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={2} sm={4} md={6} lg={7.3} >
            Company 2:
          <Box
                sx={{ flexGrow: 1, alignItems: "baseline" }}
                display="flex"
                justifyContent="flex-end"
                alignItems="flex-end">
                <Grid item sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }} spacing={{ xs: 1, md: 2, lg: 2 }} columns={{ xs: 2, sm: 2, md: 12, lg: 22 }} display="flex"
                    justifyContent="center"
                    alignItems="center" marginLeft={8} marginRight={1} mt={4} mb="30px" width='100%'>

                    <Autocomplete
                        id="input"
                        options={allCompanies}
                        renderInput={(params) => {
                            const { InputLabelProps, InputProps, ...rest } = params;
                            return <InputBase placeholder='Search for a company...' sx={{ color: light ? "white" : "black", width: "100%" }} {...params.InputProps} {...rest} />
                        }}
                        onChange={(event, value) => fetchCompanyData(value)}
                        color="primary"
                        style={{ width: "75%", border: light ? "1px solid white" : "1px solid black", borderRadius: "15px", padding: "10px" }}
                        defaultValue={companyData.name}
                    />

                </Grid>


            </Box>
              </Grid>

        </Grid>

      </Box>

     
        
          {chartData ? <CompanyChart dataset={chartData} companyName={companyData.name} companyName2={companyData.name}/>:<div> Loading chart...</div>}
```

I need to assign `companyData.name` of Company 1 to `companyName` in the above line.
I have tried using React.useState for this purpose. But I am unable to set the state inside a UI component.

```
const [company1,setCompany1]=React.useState([]);

setCompany1(companyData.name)
```

Any help regarding how to proceed would be appreciated. I just need to pass the names of 2 companies to .

Comment: you use default value of `useState` is array and you assign value as `string` in `setCompany1(companyData.name).

Answer (score 0):

You are using an array as default state ([]) and then trying to pass a string as a value setCompany(companyData.name).

Try this:

```
const [company1,setCompany1]=React.useState('');

setCompany1(companyData.name)
```